# Creating a Connection String and Working with SQL Server LocalDB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, localdb

I have problem when i try to connect to localdb from visual studio 15.
I have installed SQL Server Express 2016

I folowing this tutorial: http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/creating-a-connection-string

I create model and context(MovieDBContext) class and try to setup connection:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext"    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

When i try to access to page where i show all movies :

```
 public ActionResult Index()
 {
     return View(db.Movies.ToList());
 }
```

I get this exception:
[image]

I try to edit connection strings like this and also not working:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-MvcMovie-20130603030321;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MovieDBContext"   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>  </connectionStrings>
```

I get this excpetion when i use `(local)MSSQLLocalDB`

[image]

What i do wrong ?

Comment: In Visual Studio, on the Tools Menu, can you connect to the database? Your database should be appearing in the Server Explorer, where you can find the correct connectionString.

Comment: What is the name of the class that inherits from DbContext?Your "db" class?

Comment: If you open Sql Server Management Studio can you login to (LocalDb)\v11.0

Comment: if you have a db already (.mdf file) your AttachDbFileName should be pointing to the right path

Comment: @Forlani there's nothing wrong with his connection string.He's using EF code first and if the .mdf file doesn't exist it will be created.

Comment: You can try using SqlLocalDB Utility ( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh212961.aspx ) for investigation...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The initial Catalog is missing in `MovieDBContext` connection string.
It needs to be as follows:

```
 <add name="MovieDBContext"   connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Movies.mdf;Initial Catalog=Movies;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

Comment: Thanks this work and `.mdb` is created inside App_Data